# With dbplyr, how to add a row to a table unless the row already exists? rows_insert() is too strict and rows_append() too lax

Tags: sql, r, sqlite, dbplyr

In R, is there a way to use `dbplyr` functions, without added SQL, to add a row to a database table unless the row already exists, thus avoiding duplication?  In the example below, I add red apples to a table but then cannot add green apples with `rows_insert()` because apples already exist.  `rows_append()` would let me add green apples, but multiple times.  Some SQL for how to add a row unless it already exists is shown, but can it be done with regular `dbplyr` functions?

```r
suppressPackageStartupMessages({
  library(dplyr)
  library(dbplyr)
  library(DBI)
})

con <- DBI::dbConnect(RSQLite::SQLite())

# Create database with one table and three columns: id, fruit, colour
create_db <- "CREATE TABLE fruits(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, fruit TEXT, colour TEXT)" |> as.sql(con)
DBI::dbExecute(con, create_db)
#> [1] 0

fruits <- tbl(con, "fruits")

# Apples can be red
red_apple <- tibble(fruit = "apple", colour = "red")

# Insert into the database; primary key autoincrements and id will be assigned
rows_insert(fruits, red_apple, copy = TRUE, conflict = "ignore", in_place = TRUE)
#> Matching, by = "fruit"
fruits
#> # Source:   table<fruits> [1 x 3]
#> # Database: sqlite 3.41.2 []
#>      id fruit colour
#>   <int> <chr> <chr>
#> 1     1 apple red

# Inserting the same colour fruit doesn't work.
rows_insert(fruits, red_apple, copy = TRUE, conflict = "ignore", in_place = TRUE)
#> Matching, by = "fruit"
fruits
#> # Source:   table<fruits> [1 x 3]
#> # Database: sqlite 3.41.2 []
#>      id fruit colour
#>   <int> <chr> <chr>
#> 1     1 apple red

# Apples can also be green
green_apple <- tibble(fruit = "apple", colour = "green")

# I would like this new row to be added to the database, but this doesn't do it.
rows_insert(fruits, green_apple, copy = TRUE, conflict = "ignore", in_place = TRUE)
#> Matching, by = "fruit"
fruits
#> # Source:   table<fruits> [1 x 3]
#> # Database: sqlite 3.41.2 []
#>      id fruit colour
#>   <int> <chr> <chr>
#> 1     1 apple red

# Cherries can be red, and this works, even though the colour is duplicated.
red_cherry <- tibble(fruit = "cherry", colour = "red")
rows_insert(fruits, red_cherry, copy = TRUE, conflict = "ignore", in_place = TRUE)
#> Matching, by = "fruit"
fruits
#> # Source:   table<fruits> [2 x 3]
#> # Database: sqlite 3.41.2 []
#>      id fruit  colour
#>   <int> <chr>  <chr>
#> 1     1 apple  red
#> 2     2 cherry red

# To be added with rows_insert() the fruit must be different from anything there
yellow_lemon <- tibble(fruit = "lemon", colour = "yellow")
rows_insert(fruits, yellow_lemon, copy = TRUE, conflict = "ignore", in_place = TRUE)
#> Matching, by = "fruit"
fruits
#> # Source:   table<fruits> [3 x 3]
#> # Database: sqlite 3.41.2 []
#>      id fruit colour
#>   <int> <chr> <chr>
#> 1     1 apple red
#> 2     2 cherry red
#> 3     3 lemon yellow

# rows_append() will add the green apple ...
rows_append(fruits, green_apple, copy = TRUE, in_place = TRUE)
fruits
#> # Source:   table<fruits> [4 x 3]
#> # Database: sqlite 3.41.2 []
#>      id fruit  colour
#>   <int> <chr>  <chr>
#> 1     1 apple  red
#> 2     2 cherry red
#> 3     3 lemon  yellow
#> 4     4 apple  green

# ... but it will allow adding it multiple times, creating duplicates.
rows_append(fruits, green_apple, copy = TRUE, in_place = TRUE)
rows_append(fruits, green_apple, copy = TRUE, in_place = TRUE)
fruits
#> # Source:   table<fruits> [6 x 3]
#> # Database: sqlite 3.41.2 []
#>      id fruit  colour
#>   <int> <chr>  <chr>
#> 1     1 apple  red
#> 2     2 cherry red
#> 3     3 lemon  yellow
#> 4     4 apple  green
#> 5     5 apple  green
#> 6     6 apple  green

# This SQL statement will add a yellow apple once ...
add_yellow_apple <- "INSERT INTO fruits (fruit, colour) SELECT 'apple', 'yellow' WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM fruits WHERE fruit = 'apple' AND colour = 'yellow');" |> as.sql(con)
DBI::dbExecute(con, add_yellow_apple)
#> [1] 1

fruits
#> # Source:   table<fruits> [7 x 3]
#> # Database: sqlite 3.41.2 []
#>      id fruit  colour
#>   <int> <chr>  <chr>
#> 1     1 apple  red
#> 2     2 cherry red
#> 3     3 lemon  yellow
#> 4     4 apple  green
#> 5     5 apple  green
#> 6     6 apple  green
#> 7     7 apple  yellow

# ... and only once, as desired, never creating a duplicate.
DBI::dbExecute(con, add_yellow_apple)
#> [1] 0

fruits
#> # Source:   table<fruits> [7 x 3]
#> # Database: sqlite 3.41.2 []
#>      id fruit  colour
#>   <int> <chr>  <chr>
#> 1     1 apple  red
#> 2     2 cherry red
#> 3     3 lemon  yellow
#> 4     4 apple  green
#> 5     5 apple  green
#> 6     6 apple  green
#> 7     7 apple  yellow
```

Comment: Specify the keys - `by = c("fruit", "colour")`?

Comment: From [`?rows`](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/rows.html): *"`rows_upsert()` inserts or updates depending on whether or not the key value in ‘y’ already exists in ‘x’. Key values in ‘y’ must be unique."*. Is that what you're looking for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need specify the `by` to get the correct key in a way that `dplyr` can see it.

```r
suppressPackageStartupMessages({
  library(dplyr)
  library(dbplyr)
  library(DBI)
})

con <- DBI::dbConnect(RSQLite::SQLite())

# Create database with one table and three columns: id, fruit, colour
create_db <- "CREATE TABLE fruits(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, fruit TEXT, colour TEXT)" |> as.sql(con)
DBI::dbExecute(con, create_db)
#> [1] 0

fruits <- tbl(con, "fruits")

red_apple <- tibble(fruit = "apple", colour = "red")
green_apple <- tibble(fruit = "apple", colour = "green")
orange <- tibble(fruit = "orange", colour = "orange")
red_cherry <- tibble(fruit = "cherry", colour = "red")

# Insert into the database; primary key autoincrements and id will be assigned
in_place <- TRUE

rows_insert(fruits, red_apple, , by = c("fruit", "colour"),
            copy = TRUE, conflict = "ignore", in_place = in_place)
rows_insert(fruits, orange, by = c("fruit", "colour"),
            copy = TRUE, conflict = "ignore", in_place = in_place)
rows_insert(fruits, green_apple, by = c("fruit", "colour"),
            copy = TRUE, conflict = "ignore", in_place = in_place)
rows_insert(fruits, green_apple, by = c("fruit", "colour"),
            copy = TRUE, conflict = "ignore", in_place = in_place)
rows_insert(fruits, red_cherry, by = c("fruit", "colour"),
            copy = TRUE, conflict = "ignore", in_place = in_place)

#> Matching, by = "fruit"
fruits
#> # Source:   table<fruits> [4 x 3]
#> # Database: sqlite 3.41.2 []
#>      id fruit  colour
#>   <int> <chr>  <chr> 
#> 1     1 apple  red   
#> 2     2 orange orange
#> 3     3 apple  green 
#> 4     4 cherry red
```

<sup>Created on 2023-06-07 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Note that if you switch `in_place` to `FALSE` and use `show_query()`, you can see the SQL that `dbplyr` is generating to implement this. While this doesn't work to create the table for some reason, you can see why setting the correct key is necessary.

```
> rows_insert(fruits, red_cherry, by = c("fruit", "colour"),
+             copy = TRUE, conflict = "ignore", in_place = in_place) %>% show_query()
<SQL>
SELECT *
FROM `fruits`
UNION ALL
SELECT NULL AS `id`, *
FROM (
  SELECT *
  FROM `dbplyr_080`
  WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1 FROM `fruits`
    WHERE (
      `dbplyr_080`.`fruit` = `fruits`.`fruit` AND
      `dbplyr_080`.`colour` = `fruits`.`colour`
    )
  )
)
```

Comment: Thank you! I didn't see how ```by``` worked here, but that does it.