# With dbplyr, how to use rows_insert() but avoid duplications on NA values?

Tags: r, sqlite, dbplyr

This follows on from an earlier question, [With dbplyr, how to add a row to a table unless the row already exists? rows_insert() is too strict and rows_append() too lax](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76419175/854346).  That solution works perfectly when all values in the row I want to insert into a database exist.  But what about when the row contains an NA?  It can be added multiple times.  NA in R is special, but I'm not sure why its specialness is causing this behaviour.

```
suppressPackageStartupMessages({
  library(dplyr)
  library(dbplyr)
  library(DBI)
})

con <- DBI::dbConnect(RSQLite::SQLite())

# Create database with one table and three columns: id, fruit, colour
create_db <- "CREATE TABLE fruits(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, fruit TEXT NOT NULL, colour TEXT)" |> as.sql(con)
DBI::dbExecute(con, create_db)
#> [1] 0

fruits <- tbl(con, "fruits")

# Grapes
red_grape <- tibble(fruit = "grape", colour = "red")

# Insert into the database; primary key autoincrements and id will be assigned
rows_insert(fruits, red_grape, copy = TRUE, conflict = "ignore", in_place = TRUE, by = c("fruit", "colour"))
fruits
#> # Source:   table<fruits> [1 x 3]
#> # Database: sqlite 3.41.2 []
#>      id fruit colour
#>   <int> <chr> <chr>
#> 1     1 grape red

# Inserting the same identical fruit doesn't work.  Good.
rows_insert(fruits, red_grape, copy = TRUE, conflict = "ignore", in_place = TRUE, by = c("fruit", "colour"))
fruits
#> # Source:   table<fruits> [1 x 3]
#> # Database: sqlite 3.41.2 []
#>      id fruit colour
#>   <int> <chr> <chr>
#> 1     1 grape red

# But an grape with an NA value ...
colourless_grape <- tibble(fruit = "grape", colour = NA)

# ... can be inserted twice ...
rows_insert(fruits, colourless_grape, copy = TRUE, conflict = "ignore", in_place = TRUE, by = c("fruit", "colour"))
rows_insert(fruits, colourless_grape, copy = TRUE, conflict = "ignore", in_place = TRUE, by = c("fruit", "colour"))
fruits

#> # Source:   table<fruits> [3 x 3]
#> # Database: sqlite 3.41.2 []
#>      id fruit colour
#>   <int> <chr> <chr>
#> 1     1 grape red
#> 2     2 grape NA
#> 3     3 grape NA

# ... though not if you don't match on the column with the NA, because a grape is already there.
rows_insert(fruits, colourless_grape, copy = TRUE, conflict = "ignore", in_place = TRUE, by = c("fruit"))
rows_insert(fruits, colourless_grape, copy = TRUE, conflict = "ignore", in_place = TRUE, by = c("fruit"))
fruits
#> # Source:   table<fruits> [3 x 3]
#> # Database: sqlite 3.41.2 []
#>      id fruit colour
#>   <int> <chr> <chr>
#> 1     1 grape red
#> 2     2 grape NA
#> 3     3 grape NA
```

I would like a general solution so changing the columns in the data won't require more changes to the code.  One solution is to drop columns that contain NAs (here using `purrr` to run through all the columns).

```
grape_no_na <- colourless_grape |> purrr::discard(~all(is.na(.)))
grape_no_na
#> # A tibble: 1 × 1
#>   fruit
#>   <chr>
#> 1 grape

rows_insert(fruits, grape_no_na, copy = TRUE, conflict = "ignore", in_place = TRUE, by = colnames(grape_no_na))
 fruits
#> # Source:   table<fruits> [3 x 3]
#> # Database: sqlite 3.41.2 []
#>      id fruit colour
#>   <int> <chr> <chr>
#> 1     1 grape red
#> 2     2 grape NA
#> 3     3 grape NA
```

This works, but it's manipulating the data before `dbplyr` and the database are used.  Is there a general way to handle NAs in `dbplyr` itself so duplication won't happen?